# NodeJS - Express get referer/ redirect origin

Tags: php, node.js, express, redirect

Is there a better way to get the origin of a redirect/link (referer) instead of using

```
if (request.headers.referrer !== undefined || request.headers.referer !== undefined) {}
```

This code won't work for some browsers that do not support 'referer'.

I want to only allow users access if they are redirected from a specific location (let's say `anylink.com)`. I tried to give the link a special random generated number but once someone has the number this person can just access the site.

I am working with PHP too, so anything that's possible would be nice.

> Example: user is 'anydomain.com' (not mine) that sends him to mydomain.com. mydomain.com disallows every 'direct' connections but allows the user to access this site because the user comes from 'anydomain.com'

as PHP session is limited to the domain.
Any help would be nice! Thank you!

Comment: You're trying to implement access security using an incredibly weak mechanism.  There is simply no way to make that scheme work well (reliable and secure).  You either use a redirect and accept that it's ridiculously simple to defeat or you change your design to use something that could be more reliable and secure (such as user authentication).

Comment: FYI, a redirect header is not a reliable security mechanism by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: @jfriend00 That's not what I asked. I just want to now if there is any way.

Comment: Any way to do what?  You've already found the referrer header is not reliable and you've nixed the generated number because it's insecure so it's unclear what you're asking.  You nixed an insecure option so it appears you want something that is secure.  It is completely unclear what your requirements actually are or what you're actually asking for.

Comment: Do you have an official integration with `anydomain.com`? There might be some way to authenticate them that way. Anything that depends on the client can be spoofed (as you've seen).